# Getting value of php that is json_encode

Tags: php, jsonencoder

Hello im trying to get the value of an element that is json_encoded.

```
  public function getDescription($noArticle){
  $stmt = $this->prepare("SELECT description FROM Inventaire WHERE noArticle = '{$noArticle}' ");
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  return json_encode($result);
```

This returns me - > [{"description":"BMW M3"}] that is json_encoded.

I want to get only the "BMW M3"" part

I tried :

```
$allo = $allo->getDescription(1);
$test = json_decode($allo);
echo $test->{"description"};
```

not working if anyone could help me.
Thanks

Comment: You have __array of objects__.

Comment: What about `echo $test[0]->description;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is an array of objects, you should use:

```
$allo = '[{"description":"BMW M3"}]';
$test = json_decode($allo);
echo $test[0]->description;
```

Answer (score 0):

[{"description":"BMW M3"}] is an object within an array. So this should work:

```
echo $test[0]->description;
```

Comment: @Anasde That's nice to hear. Could you then follow protocol and upvote the correct answers? Since two people provided a correct answer you should also mark one of them as accepted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable $allo is an array of one element, you should get this first element then get your object like this:

```
$test[0]->description
```